# Break a programm with a loop

Tags: java

I wrote a code which calculates grades. But if I'm typing 9999 in the console, then the program should break without any output. How can I do this and which loop should I use? I tried it with a while loop but the program gives me still output.. this is my code with the while loop which doesn't work as it should. The Programm works except for the while loop. How can I do write this better?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class average {

    public static double average (double [] grade ){

        double sum = 0;
        int number = grade.length;

        for(int i = 0; i<grade.length; i++){
            sum+=grade[i];
        }

        double average = sum / number;
        return average;

    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How much grades you add?");

int number = s.nextInt();

while(number == 9999){
    break;
}

double [] grade = new double [number];

System.out.println("Please enter : ");

for(int i = 0; i<grade.length; i++){
    grade[i] = s.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("My grades are: ");
        for(int i = 0; i<grade.length; i++){
            System.out.println(grade[i] + " | ");

        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("My average: " +average(grade));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a *break*, which immediately exits *only the loop*. If you want to quit the program, you should use *if* and *return* like this:

```
if(number == 9999) {
    return;
}
```

This quits the program because with *return*, you exit the current function. The current function is main(), that's the program's main code. So, if you exit it, you will quit the program.

In functions with a return value (non-*void* functions) you need to specify the return value like this:

```
return 9999;
```

If you are on an other program thread, you need to call *System.exit(0)*.

Comment: That works. But whats is happening if i write return; ? why quit this my programm

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to break any loop, you just need to exit the program.

```
if (number == 9999) { 
   System.exit(); 
}
```